# Can I decrypt data which is encrypted by Keyczar using Google Tink?

Tags: tink, keyczar

I have been using Google Keyczar for encrypting data in my JAVA app. And I want to change the crypto solution to Google Tink.

But the problem is the already encrypted data by Keyczar. Can I decrypt them by Tink?

If yes, I want to change the crypto solution from Keyczar to Tink. If no, I have to think about another solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, can you show me how you're using Keyczar?

Answer (score 0):

I did it.
Keyczar is using AES. So I use TinyAES.
Keyczar is also using HMAC. So I use HMAC of avr-crypto-lib.

Just one thing is I have to extract the key from Keyczar key.

Comment: It would be useful to at least indicate library versions.

Comment: Hi, can you post some code on the answer?I'm on the same boat ;)